# What is correct sequence when release object?

Tags: objective-c

I learned a way of releasing a object like this.

```
NSMutableString *string1 = [[NSMutableString alloc]initWithFormat:@"ABCDEF"];
 :
progress some code.
 :
string1 = nil;
[string1 release];
```

Question is like below.

string1 = nil;  <= lost string1 pointer by assigning nil.

And then, [string1 release];  <= Can send a message to string1 reciever?

1. string1 = nil;

   [string1 release];
2. [string1 release];

   string1 = nil;

   What is correct sequence?

   [Additional question..]

   Is it possible to declare @property of object(NSString, NSNumner, NSARRAY...) that is in custom method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This doesn't actually accomplish what you're trying to do. It only seems to work because Objective C allows you to send messages to nil object pointers. You are correct in your example that you lose the pointer to the allocated memory and as such, leave it unreleased.

The correct way to do this would be to just call release on the string, and then set it to nil (second scenario in your example).

---

As an aside, note that if *string1* was a class property with the retain keyword then you could do something like this:

```
self.string1 = nil;
```

And this would actually release the variable. This relies on an implementation detail related to synthesize, so you don't have to worry about it re: your original question. Just an interesting side note.

Answer (score 2):

Your #2 is the correct sequence. First you release the object you allocated, and then you set the pointer to `nil` to prevent doing anything else with it (the now-unreliable address) afterwards.

In #1, once you set a pointer to `nil`, it's no longer pointing to the actual object, so calling `release` on the (nil) pointer doesn't cause an error but doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 0):

Some additional info about what Perception has explained. A synthesized setter generates code that looks somewhat like the following (for `@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *string`):

```
- (void)setString:(NSString *)newString
{
   if ([string isEqualToString:newString]) return;

   [string autorelease];
   string = [newString copy];
}
```

Now when string would have a current value `test` and newString a value `nil`, then the string would be released and no copy would take place, since the `copy` message gets send to `nil`. This is why `self.string = nil` would properly release the string while at the same time would set it's pointer to nil.

Comment: Is it possible to declare @property of object(NSString, NSNumner, NSARRAY...) that is in custom method?

Comment: I guess you wonder if you can override the synthesized methods (getters / setters)? Yes, you can.